# Connect excel to different user with same server

Tags: excel, oracle

In excel, I've a connection to an Oracle user (schema) on a particular server (let's call the server SER1 and the schema USR1).

I want to retrieve data from another schema (USR2), that is located on the same TNS server (SER1) than USR1.

So I go to data ribbon on excel, New Query -> From Database -> from Oracle Database -> SER1 -> then I see the list of all schema, fine, I click on USR2, no tables are showed... My guess is that excel is still connected with USR1 credentials and as USR1 have no grants on USR2 schema, I cannot see/retrieve the data from USR2. So my question is: how can I have a connection to USR2? On the same server SER1.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried starting  with USR2? and also have  you checked if USR2 has any  table/views using different tools like sqlDeveloper?

Comment: Yes, USR2 has tables and views, I've created a view to retrieve only what I need. I've tried the following: connect to oracle, enter SER1, click on USR2 (in the schema list), but then, no table/view are showed. And that is because, I believe, when I connect to SER1 it is automatically a connection as USR1, and other schema are showed but can be accessed only if grants are made from those to USR1.